# ObjectDataSource 'odsX' could not find a non-generic method 'methodX' that has no parameters

Tags: gridview, objectdatasource

i have an object datasource that is referring to an method with a optional parameter. i get this error when i load the page

"ObjectDataSource 'odsX' could not find a non-generic method 'methodX' that has no parameters."

this is the method signature

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public static xCollection methodX(bool defaulValue = false)
```

this is the objectdatasource connected to a gridview in a page

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsX" runat="server" TypeName="XXX"
        SelectMethod="methodX" 
        OnSelected="odsX_Selected"
        DeleteMethod="Delete">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="xId" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

why doesn't objectdatasource work with optional parameters? help?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public static xCollection methodY()
    {
      methodX();
    }
```

Then use methodY in the aspx.